# Can anyone explain the output of this program based on pointers?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main() 
{ 
 int a; 
 char *x; 
 x = (char *) &a; 
 a = 2; 
  cout<<"a"<<x<<"p"<<*x<<"d\n";
 x[0] = 1; 
 x[1] = 2; 
 cout<<a;
 return 0;
}
```

Output

apd

513

This question is a modified form of one on geeksforgeeks.org . The reason behind the second print statement is clear to me. I am unable to understand why the value and address of x is blank.
Note: The second output is machine dependant. It's value is 513 in a little endian machine

Comment: What is sizeof( int ) in your system?

Comment: the sizeof (int) is 4 bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`operator<<` for `ostream` is overloaded for `const char*`. It considers the pointer received a pointer to a null terminated C-string and tries to print the string. If you want to print the pointer value you need to convert it to `void *`, e.g.:

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(x) << endl;
```

---

again, `operator<<` is overloaded for `char` type. It prints the character, not the integer value. If you want to see the actual integer value underneath, you need to cast the char to another integer type:

```
cout << static_cast<int>(*x) << endl;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks :). But i have declared it as char *x and not as a const char * value.

Comment: @user221478 `T` is implicitly convertible to `const T`

Comment: What does T imply in this case ?

Comment: @user221478 `T` means any type. for instance `char*` so my statement can become: `char*` is convertible to `const char*`

Comment: The conversion from `char*` to `const char*` is not a case of `T` converting to `const T`. If `T` is `char*`, then `const T` is `char* const`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley god, I am speechless. Dumbfounded at what I said. That's what happens when your hand is quicker than your mind. Ty for noticing and pointing it out. @user221478 `char *` is convertible to `const char*`